# pandas time subtraction in different columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  HOUSEID    PERSONID   STRTTIME    ENDTIME
0   2100009 210000901   800          830
1   2100009 210000901   1700         1730
2   2100009 210000901   1800         1815
3   2100009 210000902   800          830
4   2100009 210000902   1700         1800
5   2100017 210001701   745          815
6   2100017 210001701   818          826
7   2100017 210001701   1135         1200
8   2100017 210001701   1330         1345
9   2100017 210001701   1445         1500
```

calculation is done for each unique combination of `HOUSEID` and `PERSONID` which makes a person. `STRTTIME` and `ENDTIME` are start time and end time of trips in a day for each person in military format. I intend to define a new colum `DWELTIME` which is time between endtime of a trip until start time of the next trip(in the row below). I.e for the first two trips (17:00 - 08:30 = 510).

for the last trip of a person `DWELTIME` is zero since there is no next trip.

output:

```
  HOUSEID    PERSONID   STRTTIME    ENDTIME   DWELTIME
0   2100009 210000901   800          830          510
1   2100009 210000901   1700         1730         30
2   2100009 210000901   1800         1815         0
3   2100009 210000902   800          830          510
4   2100009 210000902   1700         1800         0
5   2100017 210001701   745          815          3
6   2100017 210001701   818          826          189
7   2100017 210001701   1135         1200         90
8   2100017 210001701   1330         1345         60
9   2100017 210001701   1445         1500         0
```

I have no idea how this can be done. any clues? thank you

Comment: How did you get 570? I don't understand the logic.. 17:00 - 8:30 comes out to be 510(if you mean minutes)

Comment: @YashShah it's in minutes. yes I need to edit that sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try convert those time to minutes with a user defined function. Then `groupby().shift()` to re-align `STRTTIME`:

```
def get_minutes(s):
    return s//100 * 60 + s % 100

df['DWELTIME'] = (get_minutes(df.STRTTIME)
                     .groupby([df.HOUSEID, df.PERSONID])
                     .shift(-1)
                     .sub(get_minutes(df.ENDTIME)).fillna(0)
                  )
```

Output:

```
   HOUSEID   PERSONID  STRTTIME  ENDTIME  DWELTIME
0  2100009  210000901       800      830     510.0
1  2100009  210000901      1700     1730      30.0
2  2100009  210000901      1800     1815       0.0
3  2100009  210000902       800      830     510.0
4  2100009  210000902      1700     1800       0.0
5  2100017  210001701       745      815       3.0
6  2100017  210001701       818      826     189.0
7  2100017  210001701      1135     1200      90.0
8  2100017  210001701      1330     1345      60.0
9  2100017  210001701      1445     1500       0.0
```

Comment: Good answer! I would add: df['DWELTIME'] = df['DWELTIME'].astype('int32').astype(str)